# How to convert a String to Hex and vice-versa?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

As you know , in MySQL we have HEX & UNHEX, for example when I write like this :

```
select hex("Ali");
```

the convert result is : 416C69

and the unhex is like this : `select unhex("416C69");`

In MSSQL I can't convert this, could you please give me an example for both of them ???

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a String to HEX in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219245/converting-a-string-to-hex-in-sql)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this should work

```
SELECT     hex(CAST("Ali" AS VARBINARY)) AS Expr1
```

for vice versa

```
select CONVERT(varbinary(max), "416C69");
```

This will convert to varbinary, then you can convert varbinary to varchar

[Converting a String to HEX in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219245/converting-a-string-to-hex-in-sql)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx