# cannot select row by a given varchar column where row's column has a period ('.') in it

Tags: mysql

I'm having this odd problem where I can store an email "test@gmail.com" into my DB that is either a varchar() or text() but I cannot select the row based off of the email.  If I select the column via another identifier (say, a primary key called 'email_id') then I can display the email with the period in it.  I can also select any row with email column with a varchar / text that does not have a period in it, such as "test@gmailcom".

I've replicated this on a test DB as well as my stage DB.  This is also not a code issue because I've tested and replicated this when inserting directly into the DB from the query panel.

I've tried googling it but to no avail as well.

EDIT:

Am I using varchar() and/or text() correctly?  Should it be something else?  I've seen a few SO posts (cannot find them) stating to use VarChar.

For the record, I'm using mysql WorkBench for inserting / selecting, if that makes any difference.

EDIT 2:

Here are two records:

```
client_id (PK, AI, INT, UNSIGNED), email (varchar(500), not null)
```

in the table of `client_login`.

```
client_id = 1, email = 'test@gmail.com'
```

and

```
client_id = 2, email = 'test@gmailcom'
```

The following select

```
select * from client_login where email='test@gmail.com'
```

returns 0 rows

```
select * from client_login where email='test@gmailcom'
```

returns 1 row

EDIT 3:

I can also do

```
select * from client_login where client_id=1
```

and it will show me the row where `email = 'test@gmail.com'`, which is odd because it's as if the period is in the row but it's not actually a period...

Comment: Can you show the select statement you tried?

Comment: `VARCHAR(254)` should be good for the `email` column. Are you sure you're escaping the dot while inserting in the database?

Comment: Yea, I've tried that.  Even so, do I need to escape the periods?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086918/what-characters-have-to-be-escaped-to-prevent-mysql-injections

Comment: Are you sure it's a period character? What do you get with `SELECT HEX(email) FROM client_login WHERE client_id=1`? It should be `7465737440676D61696C2E636F6D` with the `2E` near the end representing ASCII `.`. Generally `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` behave the same way superficially, with `CHAR` simply having trailing spaces and being fixed length. `VARCHAR`is preferable in almost all circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, I don't believe the problem is as stated.

Here's your "problem" [running in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d020d/1), showing that it works just fine.

I think the data in the email column is not what you think it is, especially the "dot" character.
Try updating it with hand-typed data.

---

To assist debugging this problem, try outputting the column value as hex using the [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function:

```
select HEX(email)
```

and carefully inspect the output.

Comment: I'm doing all hand-typed data.  Trust me, I wish I wasn't getting this either.  I'm pretty sure you're right though in that the dot character is not what is being inputted.  Any idea how I would go about trying to figure out what it actually is?

Comment: Thanks.  I've selected the hex at it is: "7465737440676D61696CA9636F6D".  I've found an SO post about converting it back [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339138/how-to-convert-a-string-to-hex-and-vice-versa) but not sure if that'll help.  How do I go about verifying that my periods are actually periods?

Comment: The "dot" is hex `A9` or decimal `169`, but it should be hex `2E` or decimal `46`. It is probably that mysql is rendering extended ASCII chars as a dot. Update that row with a freshly typed in value and try to figure out how it got in there and prevent it happening again

Comment: I have an odd question: my collation is latin1-default.  Would this have to do with the hex not being `2E` or `46`?  I'm not well-versed in collations and not even sure how the collation became latin1

Comment: It was due to the column having an incorrect collation as well as one or two other collations being wrong.  What a mess to fix though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the SQL mode of the server

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html

Comment: I'm not so sure - which mode setting do you think would help here?

Comment: I was taking a look at the traditional or the ansi.  I'll report back if anything helps.