# Convert hexadecimal text to regular string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How do I convert a hexadecimal text to a regular readable (varchar) string in MySQL?

Ive seen some functions to convert hex to numbers but nothing to string.

Comment: Try answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339138/how-to-convert-a-string-to-hex-and-vice-versa

Comment: Just found my own answer.

Comment: Figured it out with trial and error.

Comment: BTW, that's asking for the MSSQL version. This is for MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is:

```
select CAST(unhex('hexstringhere') AS CHAR(100))
```

Figured it out via trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function UNHEX

For a string argument str, UNHEX(str) interprets each pair of characters in the argument as a hexadecimal number and converts it to the byte represented by the number. The return value is a binary string.

```
mysql> SELECT UNHEX('4D7953514C');
        -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT 0x4D7953514C;
        -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT UNHEX(HEX('string'));
        -> 'string'
mysql> SELECT HEX(UNHEX('1267'));
        -> '1267'
```

Font: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex