# User Defined Functions in MySQL Similar to Excel User Defined Funtion for Hex to Ascii

Tags: mysql, sql, hex, user-defined-functions, sql-function

It is possible to create User Defined Functions in MySQL just as we do in excel, if Yes How to do the same.

Also, If above is possible then how do i correlate (have same usage) the MySql Function with my existing excel function pasted below:

```
Public Function HexToText(Text As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim DummyStr As String
For i = 1 To Len(Text) Step 2
If Val("&H" & (Mid(Text, i, 2))) > 31 Then DummyStr = DummyStr & 
Chr(Val("&H" & (Mid(Text, i, 2))))
DoEvents
Next i
HexToText = DummyStr
End Function
```

Please note that my Hex Data also contains Null (00) probable causing error while using Unhex

**One example Values in Hex Column:**

```
596f757220496e7465726e6574206163636f756e7420776974682044484c2042524f414442414e44204e4554205b505d204c494d4954454420686176696e6720757365726e616d652020414a57414454524156454c2077696c6c20657870697265206f6e20323031362d31302d30332032303a30303a313620506c656173652
```

**Error Result Achieved via above UnHex command :**

```
��W"��FW&�WB66�V�Bv�F�D��%$�D$�B�UB��ĔԕDTB�f��rW6W&��R�tEE$dT�v���W��&R��#b��2#��b�V6R
```

**Actual Result should have been something like:**

Your Internet account with DHL BROADBAND NET [P] LIMITED having username AJWDTRAVEL will expire on 2016-10-03 20:00:16

Comment: This question shows a remarkable lack of research, given that "MySQL User Defined Function" quickly returns:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8339138/2298301

Comment: Please note that my Hex Data also contains Null (00) probable causing error while using Unhex