# How do I search for all rows containing a given unicode character in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, unicode

I am after all cells containing the ['LINE SEPARATOR' (U+2028)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) unicode point.  Normally this is encoded as `\u+2028` or something similar.  However googling how this translates to SQL has given various options none of which seem to work ([(N'2028')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1351049/296446), [`set @hexstring = '2028';`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8929661/296446), `vchar(2028)`)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE desc LIKE '% [SOME WAY TO ESCAPE U+2028 ] %'
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-UESCAPE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSI SQL answer, may or may not work with Postgresql.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE desc LIKE U&'%\2028%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using regexp:

```
select * from mytable where desc ~ '\x2028';
```